# How to make a custom confusion matrix using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

By using `.value_counts()` on my dataframe I got a series as follows:

**Sample data:**

```
In_A_Not_In_B    116
In_C_Not_In_B    104
In_A_Not_In_C    100
In_C_Not_In_A    85
```

I need to create a matrix out of the above data as shown below. The index names have to be fetched from the column value.

**Expected output:**

```
      NOT IN
      A  B  C
   A NA 116 100
IN C 85 104 NA
```

So far I have tried with `.pivot_table()`, `.MultiIndex()` with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that your result of `value_counts` is stored in variable `df`, then:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['In'] = df['index'].str[3]
df['Not In'] = df['index'].str[-1]
df.pivot(index='In', columns='Not In', values=0)
# Not In     A      B      C
# In                        
# A        NaN  116.0  100.0
# C       85.0  104.0    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. After giving `values=1`, I am getting the expected values. However, I need to get the "In" and "Not In" in a multi-index form. can you please suggest me on the same?

Comment: @siddharthkshirsagar that part is not as straight-forward as this, not sure I can help you with that. If anything, those values are stored in `df.columns.name` and `df.index.name`. Hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I'll try to build on it.